# ADB2C Graph API: Login history goes only 7 days back

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

When calling the api, described at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/signin-list?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http

I call `GET auditLogs/signIns` but only get results for the last 7 days.
Is this because the API is in beta?

How can i get SignIns that are more in the past?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The audit logs are only retained for [7 days](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-audit-logs).

You must store them for yourself if you require a longer retention.